# How can I show the file NAME of each running process from the command-line in Windows?

Tags: command-line

I was wondering how one might get a file's NAME if one has the running process PID.

Say if i have 2 notepad.exe text files running consecutively and I run at the command line 
(code courtesy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507902/how-to-extract-a-specific-field-from-output-of-tasklist-on-the-windows-command-l):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv') do @echo %~F
```

I get the result:

```
6624 7124
```

Which Text file name is PID 6624 ? or Which Text file name is PID 7124 ?

say PID 6624 is 'findme1.txt' and PID 7124 is findme2.txt'

I do not know which of the PID processes to KILL.

I might kill the wrong process and lose vital information...

In other words: which of the above findme*.txt files is findme1.txt 
and which of the above findme*.txt files is findme2.txt ?

I only wish to kill findme1.txt and NOT findme2.txt which contains vital system information, say.

Any suggestions will be most welcome and appreciative by me. 
Thank You Very Much In Advance.

Comment: Try `"tokens=2,9 delims=,"` and tasklist with `/v` verbose parameter and then `… do @echo %~F:%~G`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is the name of the file each process is working on - if any.

### background

The trouble is that the name of the file being worked on (unlike the executable file name) this is not normally displayed in the tasklist output, or the output of any other standard command line tool I'm aware of.

A process always has an internal list of the files it has open - these are in the process "handles table". This is visible in e.g. Process Explorer, but you want a command line tool. And there is no general way to know, among all the files a process has open, which one is the document the process is opened to edit.

However. Some applications —including Notepad, the Office suite, and many others — do set the file name in their window title. e.g. "Notepad file1.txt" This is not in a consistent form from one app to another. An app can set its windows title to anything it wants. A program could, for example, put its own name first and then the file name. Whatever.

So, you want to look at window titles. Task Manager can show window titles, but you want a command-line tool. As JosefZ notes, tasklist /v can do this. (There is also a little program called tlist that will do it. It comes with the Windows Debugging Tools package.) However these will show you, in addition to the processes you want, a whole bunch of processes that don't have window names.

### answer

PowerShell to the rescue! Try this at your command prompt: (You don't have to be at c:\, that is just an example)

```
c:\> powershell -command "get-Process | where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize"
```

This will list all of the processes that have a non-empty window title.

If you want to just see processes running a particular program - like notepad - you can put that name before the first pipe, like this:

```
c:\> powershell -command "get-Process notepad | where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize"
```

This filters the output of get-Process before it reaches the rest of the commands. the where-Object command filters for non-empty window titles, and the format-table just puts the result in a neat table.

Now, let's make it easier. Put the following into a .cmd file, let's say you call it wn.cmd (wn for windowname). Put wn.cmd in some directory that's in your path. (I always create a directory called c:\progs and add that to my path, for little things like this. I put the sysinternals tools in that directory too.)

```
c:\> @echo off
c:\> powershell -command "get-Process %1 | where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize"
```

### examples

Now, at a command prompt... assuming that wn.cmd is somewhere in your path... you can just type

```
c:\> wn
```

and you'll get the complete list of processes with named windows.. like this:

```
   Id Name           MainWindowTitle
   -- ----           ---------------
 9596 chrome         How can I show the file NAME of each running process from the command-line in Windows? - Super ...
11980 cmd            Command Prompt - wn
10164 explorer       progs
10180 Horas          Horas - Fri 11
 2520 notepad        windownames.ps1 - Notepad
15348 notepad        notes2.txt - Notepad
 8304 OUTLOOK        Inbox - mailbox - Outlook
17312 powershell_ise Windows PowerShell ISE
 6140 TTool103       Alarm
```

and if you type e.g.

```
c:\> wn notepad
```

you get just the ones that are running notepad:

```
   Id Name    MainWindowTitle
   -- ----    ---------------
 6240 notepad Untitled - Notepad
13096 notepad wn.cmd - Notepad
15348 notepad notes2.txt - Notepad
```

(This selection goes by the executable name, not the window title.)

*Credit where credit is due:* I found the original powershell "script" for listing processes with named windows from [this page at powershell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/09/22/getting-process-windows-titles.aspx) . Packaging it in a .cmd file just makes it easier to use.

Comment: Thank You Jamie.
Assuming you know in ADVANCE what executable file name text 
you do not wish to kill: 'dontkillit.txt'
How to further develop the code into not killing 
the vital notepad text file while killing the unecessary ones 
achieving this with a SINGLE command line entry.
Something like (logical command line ofcourse)
'TASKKILL /PID (of killit1.txt) /PID (of killit2.txt) but do not kill the PID of dontkillit.txt'
Indeed, 'wn notepad' gets you each PID with its related notepad text file Name.
with this PID information spare the vital notepad text writing ONE command line entry.

Comment: ("dontkillit.txt" is not the executable file name.) You want a single command that will e.g. kill all notepad.exe processes other than any that have a specified file open? That seems a little risky. What if you mistype your important file name? The script would then kill all notepad processes.